# forward break label

Tags: java

How can i do forward jumps like this?? Eclipse is complaining label1 is not found...

Thx

```
public class foo {

    int xyz() {
        int b = 1;

        if (b == 0) {
            break label1;
        }

        // MORE CODE HERE

        label1:

            return 1;

    }
}
```

Comment: Eclipse is complaining because the block name has not been defined at the point in the code where you call calling it from. It is out of scope.

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to use the equivalent of `goto` in Java.  You can't, and for good reason.  Abandon ship.

Labels are included in Java for the sole reason of choosing *which* **loop or switch** to break out of, in the case of nested loops (or switch statements).  They have no other purpose, and even that single purpose is often considered dangerously close to a goto.

Comment: Actually JVM does support goto. You could use a library like BCEL to do anything with the bytecode.

Comment: @Saideira: Java is not the same thing as the JVM.  Goto is not supported in the Java programming language.  It is a reserved keyword that is illegal to use.

Answer (score 6):

Labels are only applicable to loops (and blocks in general). And you are trying to mimic a `goto`. Don't.

Comment: Actually labels apply to blocks.

Comment: @Clint yeah.. but that shouldn't be told aloud :) or the next thing you'll see is people breaking out of blocks

Comment: @Clint - Actually, labels apply to _statements_, at least according to the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.7).

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. You can only break out of an **enclosing** loop structure. You don't have a loop structure at all. Try this instead:

```
public class foo {

    int xyz() {
        int b = 1;
        boolean skip = false;

        if (b == 0) {
            skip = true;
        }

        if (!skip) {
            // MORE CODE HERE
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: enclosing the break inside a do/while loop doesnt help either..still complaining about "missing" label

Comment: I'm not a fan of flag variables either :-).  The OP's example is contrived, but would best be dealt with using a `return` in the `if` block itself or using an else block for `MORE CODE HERE`.

Comment: @Saideira - for `break label1;` to work, `label1` must be the label of a statement that _contains_ the `break`.

Answer (score 0):

I addition to the previous answers, why not just

```
if (b == 0) {
 return 1;
}
```

?

Comment: this is obviously a simplified example